# How to know Loggedin User in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

I have created one read only user and connected with the newly created user

> db.addUser("user2","test", true);

I logged in to MongoDB with command line parameters

> C:\mongodb\bin>mongo.exe -u "user2" -p "test"

I am connected to database and able to perform insert operation, though my user is read only user. I want to know

1. How to check which user is logged in ?
2. If i am logged in with correct user, how can i able to perform insert operation ?

Comment: Why do you need login? It's recommended to run mongodb without logins as far as I know.

Comment: What version of MongoDB are you using?  Are you running with `--auth` and have you created an admin user per the instructions on [configuring authentication](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Security+and+Authentication#SecurityandAuthentication-Configuring)?

Comment: To answer your second question, MongoDB does not have a complex auth system as such any user who is authed for that particular database and is not a read only user has access to all normal functions of the database.

Comment: "How to properly configure a read-only user", is a good question. There's also an outstanding ticket for checking the currently logged on user: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-7124

Comment: Cirrus, do you mean to say there is some bug related to this ?              And Sammaye, do you mean to say readOnly user is not actually readonly user and it will allow me to perform all operation without operation?

Comment: Sorry misread my first comment, yes if the user is authed and is not read only you can perform almost any action, there are a few admin commands that you can't but otherwise yes.